# Cannot organize Cassandra table structure

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE test_keyspace.persons (
    id uuid,
    name text,
    birth_date timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, birth_date)
);
```

And I have two use-cases:

1. Find persons by `id`
2. Find persons by `birth_date` (like `WHERE birth_date >= 1985/03/12 AND birth_date <= 1985/03/30`) + sort in ASC/DESC order

With current table example I'm not able to retrieve by dates between. Also I'm not able if I make `birth_date` as a partitioned key - I get an exception:

```
Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING
```

Do I need to change primary keys? Do I need separate table for my purpose? Please help me to understand how to design my data model most effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cassandra you design your tables based on your queries. Now you have two queries

1. Find persons by id
2. Find persons by birth_date (like WHERE birth_date >= 2022/03/12 AND birth_date <= 2022/03/30) + sort in ASC/DESC order

Your current table will be able to answer your first query since you are asking Cassandra to give persons by id which is your partition key.

For second query you can have another table. But since you are doing filtering based on date, you might need to create a partition which consist of a dummy partition key  and and date of birth as clustering key. Something like this

```
CREATE TABLE test_keyspace.persons_by_year (
id uuid,
name text,
birth_date timestamp,
year text,
PRIMARY KEY (year, birth_date)
```

);

Then you can query like `where year = '1985' and  birth_date >= 1985/03/12 AND birth_date <= 1985/03/30`

Another option is you can look out for spark-cassandra combo which can filter data in memory.

Comment: is there possibilities to do it without dummy column?

Comment: You could use ALLOW FILTERING option while keeping the first table structure.  But it is not recommended to use this option in production if you have large data set